# FFmpeg LGPL build

Tags: build, ffmpeg, mingw, avcodec

Hello I'm trying to build ffmpeg under the LGPL license but I'm having trouble creating the dll's.

I'm building the source on the Windows platform using MinGW and I use the configure options below to build the latest snapshot

```
./configure --enable-memalign-hack --enable-pthreads --disable-shared
```

However when I make and install from this I only get the "avdevice-53.dll" and none of the others such as avcodec or avformat. Is there something else I need to do to be able to make these files?

Comment: You need to remove the `--disable-shared` as that prevents *shared libraries* (DLLs) from being built.

Comment: I tried making it again using "./configure --enable-memalign-hack --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --disable-static" but that still only creates "avdevice-53.dll" and none of the others?

Comment: Make sure you clean your workspace first with 'make distclean'.